# Integrating strtolower + str_replace + strip_tags together?

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace, taxonomy, strip-tags

I am trying in Wordpress to use strtolower + str_replace + strip_tags together in order to make a Quicksand filter working for multiple word taxonomies.

I manage to use two, namely:

```
<?php
 echo '<li class="span4" data-id="post-'.get_the_ID().'" 
 data-type="'.$terms_as_text =  **strtolower(strip_tags**( get_the_term_list
 ($post->ID, 'tapes', '', ' ', '' ) )).'">';
 echo '<span class="title">';
 ?>
```

Is it possible to integrate also str_replace in the code above, sth like str_replace("", "-")?

I hope someone can help - just tried a series of options, but the syntax just doesnt work :(

Thanks for any help.

Comment: wrap the `strtolower` with the `str_replace` function

Comment: Thanks so much, PurityLake. I am now trying the following, but it just doesnt work and I am still quite new with the PHP-Syntax. Is it a matter of putting a bracket wrong?                               <?php echo '<li class="span4" data-id="post-'.get_the_ID().'" data-type="'.$terms_as_text = str_replace("", "-"),strtolower(strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'tapes', '', ' ', '' ) )).'">';
            
echo '<span class="title">'; ?>

Comment: For example `str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower(strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'tapes', '', ' ', '' )))`

Comment: [str_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Yippe, that worked with one more closed bracket at the end, - thanks! Now I have another issue, but at least the first part fixed...Thanks again.